# Property "File.select" is not defined Yii Framework

Tags: php, yii, cgridview

Just started to learning the yii framework couple of days ago, so I am totally new in it. The issue is while adding checkbox in my `CGridView` I am getting the following error:

```
Property "File.select" is not defined Yii Framework
```

and following is my code:

```
<?php
$this->widget('zii.widgets.grid.CGridView', array(
    'dataProvider' => $model->search(),
    'filter' => $model,
    'columns' =>
    array(
        array(
            'name' => 'select',
            'value' => 'CHtml::checkBox("cid[]",null,array("value"=>$data->id","id"=>"cid_".$data->code))',
            'type' => 'raw',
            'htmlOptions' => array('width' => 5),
        //'visible'=>false,
        ),

        array(
            'name' => 'name',
            'value' => 'CHtml::link($data->name, array("file/download", "code" => $data->code))',
            'type' => 'html'
        ),
        array(
            'name' => 'createdAt',
            'value' => '$data->createdAt',
        ),
        array(
            'class' => 'CButtonColumn',
            'updateButtonUrl' => 'CHtml::normalizeUrl(array("file/update", "code" => $data->code))',
            'deleteButtonUrl' => 'CHtml::normalizeUrl(array("file/delete", "code" => $data->code, "deleteCode" => $data->getDeleteCode()))',
            'template' => '{update} {delete}',
        )
    )
));
?>
```

When I remove checkbox array its working fine. Where I am going wrong?

Thanks.

Comment: In your model File or table File You dont have a field named select

Comment: you mean in `attributesLabel` method?

Comment: Which model are u passing to your cgridview ??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You Can also make use of class CCheckBoxColumn as shown

```
 'columns'=>array(
        array(
            'id'=>'selectedCompanies',
            'class'=>'CCheckBoxColumn',
         ),
```

To display the checkboxes

Comment: Thanks its working but its only selecting one checkbox at a time not multiple. How can I achieve this?